# What does the shmop PHP extension do?

Tags: php, shared-memory

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.shmop.php

> Shmop is an easy to use set of functions that allows PHP to read,
>   write, create and delete Unix shared memory segments.

I don't understand, what exactly is the purpose of this extension? What is it used for?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Shared memory allows multiple processes to access the same data in memory. You can use it to share data among running PHP scripts.

```
 $shm = shmop_open(0xF00, "c", 0644, 4);

 $count = unpack('L', shmop_read($shm, 0, 4));
 $count = reset($count);
 var_dump($count);
 echo "count: ", $count++, "<br/>\n";
 shmop_write($shm, pack('L', $count), 0);
```

When the computer restarts, anything in shared memory is lost.

Different processes can access the same shared memory at the same time, which can lead to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). In the example above, if two processes read the shared memory before either writes back to it, the count will be 1 less than it should be. Race conditions can be prevented by using a [mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921469/90527), but that's outside the scope of this Q&A.

Shared memory is used for one type of [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), namely data passing. Some others available in PHP (depending on the platform and PHP build) are:

- Signals ([`posix_kill`](http://php.net/posix_kill) to send a signal, [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/pcntl_signal) to set up a signal handler), a limited type of message passing. Signals aren't particularly useful in scripted pages, as each script should run for a very short time.
- [Sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) for data. Sockets can use a network, or can be local.
- Pipes for data. [`posix_mkfifo`](http://php.net/posix_mkfifo) is used to create [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) (aka [FIFOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)), and the standard [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php) functions are used to read and write data. Unnamed (aka [anonymous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe)) pipes can be created between parent and child processes using [`popen`](http://php.net/popen) or [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open). Note unnamed pipes cannot be created between arbitrary processes. Note that pipes on some systems are unidirectional: a pipe handle can be used either to read or write, but not both.
- [Semaphores](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) for [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29).
- Message queues for [messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing). In PHP, the Semaphore extension offers both message queues and another set of shared memory functions (e.g. [`shm_attach`](http://php.net/shm_attach)). Many other extensions for various messaging protocols are also available, including [SAM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sam.php), [STOMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stomp.php) and [AMQP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php). See "[Other Services](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.remote.other.php)" in the PHP manual for, well, others.
- Network [stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for data. At a lower level, these are just sockets, though they provide a different interface. They are also for specific application level protocols, whereas sockets are more general.
- [Network protocol extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.remote.other.php), such as [cURL](http://php.net/cURL), for messaging & data. Like stream wrappers, these are (limitd) sockets in disguise.
- [Web service extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php), such as [SOAP](http://php.net/SOAP) and [XML-RPC](http://php.net/XML-RPC), for [remote procedure calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (RPC). Note that while these are socket based, they're for a different type of IPC (RPC rather than data).

While sockets (and anything based on them, such as stream wrappers) and pipes can be used to pass data between processes, their abilities with more than two processes are limited. Sockets can only connect two processes; to handle more than two, multiple sockets need to be opened (which is where a client-server architecture usually comes into it). With pipes, only one process can [read given data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634580/); once it has, that data won't be available to other readers, though they can read other data (which will then become unavailable to all but the reader). An arbitrary number of processes can open the same shared memory region.

Comment: Is there a good way of making the receiving process react to a message, so that it becomes event driven?

Comment: @outis, What's the Windows equivalent?

Answer (score 9):

When a running process requests memory, the system provides a slice of memory which can only be accessed by the allocated process. Sometimes you run multiple threads and want to share data amongst them.

"Sharing data" can be done by:

- Passing data via sockets/pipes
- Shared Memory (threads, processes)

Since passing data is not very handy in some cases, one might want to use [Shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).

The functions in question provide functionality to handle shared memory segments in PHP.

Comment: So it's basically useless then? I mean if you can use global variables for that, there's no point in messing with those shmop_* functions

Comment: @Alex: PHP doesn't really have "global variables" like that. It's a misnomer in PHP, as you always have separated process spaces. -- Think of shmop more like memcache, except that it's a POSIX/Unix system feature, intended for sharing between PHP and C apps (if it weren't for the binary representation mismatch, can't find that duplicate). You can also imagine it as a ramdisk, in fact shmop usually creates a file entry in `/etc/shm/*`

Comment: Shared Memory is managed by the operating system. They have way more protection and control services compared to the limited usage of global variables. Shared memory is mostly used for interprocess-communication. If you don't explicitly need this, stick to variables.

Comment: PHP has global variables. Global variables are only global to the process they belong to. They can't be accessed in other processes.

Comment: @Fuzzy: what exactly do you mean by "passing variables"? Environment variables? Session variables? Request data (the query string and request body, accessibly as `$_GET` and `$_POST` in PHP)? Something else?

Comment: Passing Variables from one method to another during runtime. I am talking about communication between methods. As mario mentioned before, shmop could be used for communication between C and PHP but between PHP methods passing a variable would do the job as well as shared memory (but this would be a little "oversized" ...) ;)

Comment: In addition to my post: two (or more) threads of one process might use global variables instead of shared memory.

Comment: @Fuzzy: formal parameters (i.e. passed values), global variables and shared memory have different purposes. Neither formal parameters nor global variables are viable alternatives to shared memory, as neither can be accessed outside of a single process; formal parameters can't even be directly accessed outside of their scope (the function they're defined on, and any functions defined within that function).

Comment: RE: globals and threads–[globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Following the connectivity property of [capabilities programming](http://www.erights.org/elib/capability/ode/ode-capabilities.html) (which is actually a property of pure OOP), the shared data needed by a thread should be passed to it when it's created. In any case, PHP doesn't have threading built-in, so that's not relevant to a question about SHM in PHP.

Comment: @outis: I know ;). I tried adding some extra information on the topic (thats why I didn't point out the pros/cons) but I totally agree.

Comment: @Fuzzy: if you know, why do you say in your answer that passing variables can be used to share data between processes?

Comment: Oh, I edited it but forgot the word "processes". Mea culpa ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6146/discussion-between-fuzzy-and-outis)