# OpCache - understanding how the cache works, per user or per resource?

Tags: php, caching, opcache

I'm using OpCache since it came with PHP 5.5.x and I'm really pleased with it, but I would like to tune its memory settings and that's where my understanding comes short...

When a given user requests a given page, the server answers this requests, calls the PHP interpreter, the interpreter stores the opcodes in the cache, serves the content, and that's about it. The next time a request comes in, the cache kicks in if the requested opcodes are the same, but my questions is...

The cache is working on a per-user basis (and the cached opcodes apply only for this specific user's requests) or do they apply to any request making use of those cached opcodes?

What I would like to do is tune OpCache to use a certain ammount of memory but I don't know if the memory pool works on a per-user basis or it's acting like a shared pool of resources.

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are already right about how the opcode is stored in cache and read from the  shared memory. It is however not on a user basis, but rather on a script level. Each php file that has been **parsed** and **compiled** to opcode will be saved to the shared memory and executed from there. The **parsing** and **compiling** steps, which are otherwise slow, will be shortcircuited for each script that has been cached.

[image]

To answer your questions, no the cache does not work on a per-user basis but rather on per-script. The cached opcode is still executed by the scripting engine (Zend mostly) per request.

And yes it does read from the shared memory.

Reference
[D. Shafik: Everything You Need to Know About OpCode Caches](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/26902267-PHP-Performance-I-Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-OpCode-Caches)

Comment: Awesome! Exactly like I wanted for it to behave. Now I can tune the memory settings with ease. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Awemo I have confusion here about shared memory. Could you please tell me what is shared memory exactly. Hard Disk or RAM ?

Comment: @sandipshirsale It is the RAM of the server system, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8631902/199072).