# OpCache: Shared memory and settings?

Tags: php, opcache

I have questions when using OPCache.

1. Whether the different websites share the same cache/keysets of OPCache? I just make a test. I have PHP 7.4 and 8.1 installed on my server. It seems websites using PHP 7.4 will not share the same cache with those using PHP 8.1. However, for all websites using PHP 7.4, they will share the same cache.
2. Whether different websites can use different settings for OPCache, by using different php.ini under the corresponding folder?

Thank you

**Update:**

Based on my research, [OpCache - understanding how the cache works, per user or per resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329035/opcache-understanding-how-the-cache-works-per-user-or-per-resource) indicates all scripts share the same memory. However, actually for different PHP versions, based on my tests, they will use different memory.

Comment: What were your tests?