# only one client connect to named pipe mpegts in golang

Tags: go

I am currently learning about named pipes in linux using golang and C. I wrote a small server program which read a named pipe:

```
mkfifo /tmp/namedpipe.ts
ffmpeg -i url -c copy /tmp/namedpipe.ts
```

and a web server application opening the pipe like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("/tmp/namedpipe.ts")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
        http.HandleFunc("/test.ts", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
             w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "video/MP2T")
             w.Header().Add("Cache-Control", "no-store")
             w.Header().Add("Connection", "close")
             reader := bufio.NewReader(f)
    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Couldn't read line, ", err)
        }
        w.Write(line)
    }

        })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))

}
```

This works great as long as only one client connects to the pipe. It can both read and write. If I try to connect a second client, the code never exceeds the line

I would like to modify this code and add more than one client reading from Named Pipe at the same time without freezing an image and not crashing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634580/named-pipes-fifos-on-unix-with-multiple-readers

Answer (score 0):

As you use an infinite loop so that should be one break statement once the customer/Client consumes the API after downloading the file from the API it should not be a part of the loop and inside error, there should be one check for EOF and at that moment you should be break

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("/tmp/namedpipe.ts")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    http.HandleFunc("/test.ts", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "video/MP2T")
        w.Header().Add("Cache-Control", "no-store")
        w.Header().Add("Connection", "close")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(f)
        for {
            line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    break
                }
                log.Fatal("Couldn't read line, ", err)
            }
            w.Write(line)
        }

    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```